# husky pre-commit hook for 'test' does not finish

Tags: git, package.json, githooks, husky, lint-staged

Hi i installed `husky` & `lint-stage` so as to have pre-commit hooks for `lint` & `tests`, for the staged files.

The pre-commit hook works, when i go to `git commit -m 'something'`, and the commands are triggered.

**What i have so far in terms of files is:**

---

`.husky/pre-commit`:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

`.package.json`:

```
 "lint-staged": {
   "*.{ts,tsx}": "eslint --cache --fix",
   "*": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen"
  }
```

When i `git commit ..`, (2 files, 1 *.test.ts * and 1 *.ts), it starts the `linter` & the `test`, but the test never finishes unless i break it(ctrl+c).

- **the *.test.ts file, it has an error in it.**

[image]

Only when i break it, i get the errors on the screen:

[image]

Also what i notice is that the `lint-staged:` object, it is changed into package.json, when i `git commit..` :

**Initially i have it like so:**

```
 "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,tsx}": "eslint --cache --fix",
    "*.test.{ts, tsx}": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen"
 }
```

**And it turns to this:**

```
 "lint-staged": {
   "*.{ts,tsx}": "eslint --cache --fix",
   "*": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen"
 }
```

Any help on the configuration that i miss is welcome please.

Answer (score 3):

So i fixed that issue by adding the flag `--watchAll=false` in the script, we get rid of the interactions :

`react-scripts test --env=jsdom --watchAll=false --bail`

And by adding the `--bail` flag (optional), it exits on the first failing test.